# Loading page in android realm

Tags: android, realm

I want to fetch 20 records from realm data base in my android project after that fetch next 20 records and fetch other records in each step like this until fetch all of my records from realm .

this is my realm database function for get many special records

```
public ArrayList<Post> loadLikedPost() {
    ArrayList<Post> posts_database = new ArrayList<Post>();

    realm.beginTransaction();
    ListIterator<PostDatabase> posts;
    posts = realm.where(PostDatabase.class).equalTo("is_like", true).findAll().sort("post_id", Sort.DESCENDING).listIterator();
    int size = realm.where(PostDatabase.class).equalTo("is_like", true).findAll().size();
    realm.commitTransaction();

    int i = 0;

    while(posts.hasNext() && i < 20) {
        PostDatabase pd = posts.next();
        Post p = new Post();
        p.text = pd.getText();
        p.img = pd.getImg();
        p.post_id = pd.getPost_id();
        p.width = pd.getWidth();
        p.height = pd.getHeight();
        p.date = pd.getDate();
        p.is_visible = pd.getIs_visible();
        p.likes = pd.getLikes();
        p.is_like = pd.getIs_like();

        p.entity = new ArrayList<Entity>();

        for(EntityDatabase ed : pd.getEntity()) {
            Entity e = new Entity();
            e.length = ed.getLenght();
            e.offset = ed.getOffset();
            e.type = ed.getType();
            p.entity.add(e);
        }
        p.setSpan();
        p.setImg(context);
        posts_database.add(p);

        i++;
    }
    Collections.reverse(posts_database);
    return posts_database;
}
```

this is my function for loading those records that I got it from last function

```
public void loadPost() {
    Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            callDatabase = new CallDatabase(context);
            callDatabase = new CallDatabase(context);
            callListener.onGetLikedPosts(PostController.getVisiblePosts(callDatabase.loadLikedPost(i), true));
        }
    });
    thread.start();
}
```

Now I just can fetch first 20 records, what should I do ?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without some more information, that is hard to tell. Please post the code you are using now.

Comment: @SaraGorzin Using Realm.io in Iran is a violation of the [LICENSE](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/LICENSE): `You understand that the Software may contain cryptographic functions that may be
subject to export restrictions, and you represent and warrant that you are not
located in a country that is subject to United States export restriction or embargo,
including Cuba, Iran, North Korea, Sudan, Syria or the Crimea region, and that you
are not on the Department of Commerce list of Denied Persons, Unverified Parties,
or affiliated with a Restricted Entity.`

Answer (score 0):

Technically if you didn't ignore the **zero-copy** functionality of Realm, you wouldn't even need to provide pagination or loading.

```
public RealmResults<Post> loadLikedPost() { //call on UI thread
     return realm.where(Post.class)
                 .equalTo("is_like", true)
                 .findAllSortedAsync("post_id", Sort.DESCENDING); 
}
```

And then you could do

```
public class PostAdapter extends RealmRecyclerViewAdapter<Post, PostViewHolder> {
    public PostAdapter(Context context, RealmResults<Post> results) {
        super(context, results, true);
    }

    // onCreateViewHolder

    // onBindViewHolder
          //getItem(position)
}
```